# Scale image header in \fancypagestyle

Tags: fancyhdr, overleaf, png, resize

Modifying an existing template (found on overleaf),  I want to reduce the size of the logo header I am adding- top right(saved as ijisalogo.png). My image itself is a little big and I would just like to scale it on the tex file here. How do I do it?

```
\fancypagestyle{thefirstpage}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\vcenteredinclude{ijisalogo.png}}
```

This is the code for the header used in the template. (Don't ask me to change the package itself as it's a pre-made template and I don't want to change a lot besides content.)

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and edit your post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the code of the template, the only solution I can offer is to scale down the logo with a drawing program (or a command line program like those from ImageMagick).
Or get rid of the `\vcenteredinclude` and do it yourself with `\includegraphics[scale=xxx]{ijisalogo}`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum worked, thanks!